# "GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects" is not supported. [Steam]

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, opengl

I'm trying to run dota 2 reborn on my Ubuntu 13.10 but I'm getting this error...

> Required OpenGL extension "GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects" is not
>   supported. Please update your OpenGL drivers.

glxinfo | grep OpenGL gives me:

```
sandesh@sandesh-H87M-D3H:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 9.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

I've tried referring to many other sites but they're pointing to oibas ppa and my OS is giving 404 not found with ppas
also

When i try to execute this

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:amd64 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:amd64 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

This gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic
E: Unable to locate package libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

I think I'm missing few list files here ? how do I install this openGL? I'm sorry I don't have experience in installing drivers on ubuntu

Comment: I have the same problem, any solutions?